# iphone .mov systematically corrupted - annoying to move

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, photos, mov

I have a problem with my Iphone: every time I want to copy/paste the pics (and related .mov) many of these files get corrupted, meaning that either they are empty once copied on my windows laptop, or the overall process of copying /pasting gets interrupted every time one of these .mov files gets transferred. This happens both with the photos app and by manually copying the files from the windows explorer.

It's very frustrating and I'm not finding any results and I think I'm [doing it correctly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHU299wLZGw). I use iPhone 7+ with iOS 15.6.1 and Windows 10.

How can I fix or troubleshoot this?

Comment: Hello! Can you edit in some details if no one has a quick answer in a week or so? Listing the size of a video, from which app you copy them and how they then get to your windows laptop after "paste" and the iOS version might help someone try to reproduce this so you don't get / erase + restore answers on iOS.

Comment: Also the *best* way to get pics onto your PC is to install iTunes for Windows, verify the options in iTunes related to images/video are set to your likes. By default I believe they will copy images to a folder within your user folder called pictures. Then sync your iPhone using iTunes, it will copy all your pictures and movies to the PC.

Comment: @bmike thanks, I added some details

Comment: @SteveChambers I'll give a try, thanks!

Comment: Windows doesn't understand the 'container' format Apple uses for Live Photos, so the *best* you will get is a photo & a separate video.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks, yes, I think that is exactly the problem. I would still be fine with that double format, provided that the .MOV are not lost. (When transferred some are really corrupted, which makes no sense, as on the phone they work)